# How can I control or stop the paint event of the dynamic user control from the main form?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, paintevent

I have a big problem with a small matter. I'm coding a messaging app.

This is the layout I use:
Main Form --> container (UserControl) --> bubble(UserControl)

I am sending these parameters to the container

```
this.container1.addOutMessage(message, get_min_sec(time), tickStatus);
```

and container creates bubbles dynamically in itself.

```
public void addOutMessage(string message, string time, int tick_status) {...}
```

According to the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868573/how-can-i-resize-the-width-and-height-of-a-usercontrol-according-to-a-child-labe) I got in this forum, I draw the contents of the message bubbles in the Paint event. Since the width and height information was not yet clear when creating, I could not create the vertical distance between the messages correctly.

[image]

That's why I created this function.

```
public void ContaninerConfigure()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int keepBottom = 0;
        foreach (var item in container1.panel.Controls.OfType<Control>().OrderBy(ee => ee.TabIndex))
        {
            //SuspendDrawing(item);
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (counter != 0)
                {
                    item.Top = keepBottom + 10;
                    keepBottom = item.Bottom;
                }
                else keepBottom = item.Top + item.Height;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        counter = 0;
}
```

then

[image]

My problem starts here. When I add it to the container's resize event it works fine but when I call it in the main form after my messages are loaded it doesn't work at all. Paint event continues to run on **every scroll movement**. In the container's resize event, only the message bubbles that appear on the screen are aligned. It can crashes again when I scroll up. Then it is necessary to call the previous function again to align it.

I did not access Paint event in Bubble(UC) which is dynamically created in Container(UC).That's why I couldn't control with the paint event, its run or stop.

After some research I found the SuspendDrawing method. I implemented it this way but I don't want to use it. It takes 3 seconds for 25 bubbles to line up on the panel and main form stays "up to date" during compile.

There has to be a more practical way of doing this. For example, I don't know how to check the bool in the bubble(UC) from the main form.

If you have any idea about this issue, please help.

Comment: Imagine a two or maybe three hours chitchat and your app keep creating and adding controls this way. Your app will crash eventually, I promise you that. I think you need to reconsider the design and find alternatives. Like HTML viewer, a single control to **draw** everything in the view, or maybe move to WPF which provides better tools for this kind of apps. Apologies for the negativity.

Comment: This is sad news, but when I examine the structures you mentioned, I understand what you mean, you're right. I'm asking in order not to waste time because I need to finish it soon. Which side do you use your preference? Which path should I follow with the fewest possible changes to the existing logic? And on the other hand, which one should I use for the best results?

Comment: See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181555/SignalChat-WPF-SignalR-Chat-Application) as WPF example. Some more examples in YouTube.

Comment: You can do something like this, if you need to *finish soon*: [Fake-scrolling containers with very many controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39810717/7444103). Use a *virtual UserControl* that exists only in the View, so you don't allocate graphics resources and handles (it's a race between the two for which will kill the app first).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll try the fake scroll event first. It looks like it'll save me if I can.